# Android Room: TypeConverter for Option<MyVal>: Migration has issue with notNull property

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

With Room, I can't seem to figure out how to make a `TypeConverter` to convert the TEXT coming back from the Sqlite DB into an `Option`-wrapped `UUID`. (Or even `Option`-wrapped `String`)

```
object GuidConverter {
  @JvmStatic @TypeConverter fun toDb(o: Option<UUID>): String? = 
    o.fold(
      {null},
      {it.toString()})

  @JvmStatic @TypeConverter fun fromDb(s: String?): Option<UUID> = 
    when(s) {
      null -> None
      else -> Some(UUID.fromString(s))
    }

@Entity(...)
@TypeConverters(GuidConverter::class)
data class MyTable(
  val id: Long = 0, 
  val guid: Option<UUID> = None)
```

My migration defines the column `guid`: `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN guid TEXT`. I do not have `NOT NULL` in the command.

But when I run the app, `IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle mytable`:

```
Expected:
    TableInfo{name='mytable', columns={guid=Column{name='guid', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, ...}, ...}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='mytable', columns={guid=Column{name='guid', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, ...}, ...}
```

Why is `notNull=true` in the Expected? My TypeConverter clearly identifies the conversion to DB format as being `String?`.

Comment: please add your `TableInfo` class too.

Comment: @NaveenNiraula TableInfo is a class belonging to Google's Room, not me.

Comment: But if you really want to see it, Google has it hosted here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/room/runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/util/TableInfo.java

Comment: I meant the name `mytable` can I see it because you may have missed a @NonNull there.

Comment: `MyEntity` and `mytable` are the same thing. I missed that discrepancy when typing my code here. I'll edit. And I didn't miss a @NotNull because the field is supposed to be nullable. Before applying typeconverter it is a nullable String in the DB, and after applying the typeconverter it is an Option<UUID> in the application side.

Comment: The problem is that the generated Room code expects notnull (but should not) but the actual table field IS nullable.

Comment: You can just do this to solve the problem `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN guid TEXT NOT NULL`

Comment: No I cannot. The app has Option<UUID> turns out into String?. the table stores that, a nullable string